# Стиль на кнопке. WPF

Tags: wpf

Недавно начал изучать WPF. И наткнулся на проблему, когда наводишь на кнопку она становится голубой. Поискав в интернете нашёл решение проблемы. И я сделал стиль на кнопку. Но вот проблема, стиль на кнопку не применяется. P.S
На элементах внутри кнопки прозрачный фон.

Стиль:

```
 <Style x:Key = "TriggerStyle" TargetType = "Button">
     <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value = "Blue" />
     <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property = "IsMouseOver" Value = "True">
            <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value = "Green" />
        </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Кнопка:

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="#FF141414">
    <Button Content="Main" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonSubMenu}" FontSize="22"/>
    <StackPanel Height="114" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Background="#FF232323">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource TriggerStyle}" Height="30" Background="#FF2D2D2D" 
            Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Width="181" Height="30">
                <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Terminal" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              Width="26" StretchDirection="DownOnly" Height="22" Margin="0,4"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Console" FontSize="18" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы изменить поведение по умолчанию при MouseOver нужно изменить ControlTemplate 
Попробуй:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259280/how-do-you-change-background-for-a-button-mouseover-in-wpf

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы каждый раз не создавать новый стиль для нового цвета, а просто к ARGB прибавлять 10?

Comment: Лучше в рамках нового вопроса задать.